# Flex 4.6 transform generic Object to Class Instance

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Hey when I have an "Object" instance that doens't belong to any other class, how can I cast this to a class instance?

**Example**

A simple User class

```
public class User
{
    public var name:String;
}
```

When I try to cast

```
var obj:Object = new Object;
obj.name = "Alex";

var user:User = User(obj);
```

Flex gives me this error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
>   Object@97a52b1 to models.User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably impossible, because User doesn't (automatically like in Java) extend Object class.

And if you would extend it, then the .name property would be lost through the type casting.

So you will have to create a new Object object and populate it "by hand".

```
   myObj = {};
   for (var key:String in myUser) 
             myObj[key] = myUser[key];
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I solved this this quite similar by using a "populate" method on the User class which I can pass the the generic object to.